# Scheduling Python Scripts on Linux

Tags: python, linux, cron

I've been looking around for a while for the best way to do this, but not really getting very far. I have a python script that is running several times a day on a cron, this script determines the times and dates that another script needs to be scheduled to run. The times, dates and durations that this script need to run on varies dramatically, and they are one-off events.

My problem is how to actually schedule these events. Can anyone advise a suitable python or linux method?

Thanks

UPDATE: Thanks chaps for the prompt.

For anyone else searching this, this is what I did, for script foobar.py to run at 9.15am on Jul 14th:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python foobar.py | at 9.15am Jul 14',], shell=True)
```

Comment: There's `at` for one-off scheduled jobs.

Comment: OP: I find it hard to believe that the `POpen` command you have works. Unless `foobar.py` outputs a bash script for `at` to run.

Comment: I think you may be correct Thanatos, I hadn't fully tested the solution when I updated. Can you suggest a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `at` command from the python script.  See the documentation [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at).

Answer (score 1):

```
import time,sched;
```

I think sched is something you are looking for